# Not fetching object from cache - Parse

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform

I am having some problems with cache policy where it is not fetching objects from the cache. Here is the function that I call to fetch my object:

```
func findEmployeeForLoggedInUser(completion: (array: [AnyObject], error: String?) -> Void) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Employee")
        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.cacheElseNetwork
        query.whereKey("employerId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
            var employeeArray = [PFEmployee]()
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                completion(array: employeeArray, error: errorString)
            } else {
                for employee in results! {
                    let currentEmployee: PFEmployee = employee as! PFEmployee
                    employeeArray.append(currentEmployee)
                }
                completion(array: employeeArray, error: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the body of this function, I have declared the cache policy of the `PFQuery` to be `cacheElseNetwork`. However, when I try to retrieve my objects by calling this function, it does not work entirely, as it is not retrieving the data.I have also disabled that Parse local datastore. Additionally, I clear all cached results every time a user logs back in.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you executed queries previous to this one where you pulled in the data FROM the network then PINNED the data locally?

Comment: You say it isn't retrieving any data. What if you disable the cache?  Then does your query retrieve any data? If `employerId` is a reference or pointer type then you would normally just say `whereKey("employerId", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way it works:

First off, from Parse:

> Parse also lets you store objects in a local datastore on the device
>   itself. You can use this for data that doesn't need to be saved to the
>   cloud, but this is especially useful for temporarily storing data so
>   that it can be synced later. To enable the datastore, add
>   libsqlite3.dylib and call [Parse enableLocalDatastore] in your
>   AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions: before calling
>   [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:]. Once the local datastore is
>   enabled, you can store an object by pinning it.

Now that we know this, then you must PIN you data to the local storage, this is what this means:

```
let gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
gameScore.pinInBackground()
```

then to retreive it, you must do this, also from Parse:

Retrieving Objects from the Local Datastore

> Storing an object is only useful if you can get it back out. To get
>   the data for a specific object, you can use a PFQuery just like you
>   would while on the network, but using the fromLocalDatastore method to
>   tell it where to get the data.

Then this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZ4YEGZ").continueWithBlock({
  (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
  if task.error != nil {
      // There was an error.
      return task
  }

  // task.result will be your game score
  return task
})
```

then this also from parse:

> If you already have an instance of the object, you can instead use the
>   fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackground method.

then this:

```
let object = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"GameScore", objectId:"xWMyZ4YEGZ")
object.fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackground().continueWithBlock({
  (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
  if task.error != nil {
      // There was an error.
      return task
  }

  // task.result will be your game score
  return task
})
```

If you got to the end of this, then you may soon find out that this functionality is still very much a "black box". It DOES work, but you may find that you have unexpected results from retrieving data. If you truly have data that doesn't need refreshing then by all means use the local cache, but it gets sort of messy sometimes when you need to "fetch" and update and make sure you are timing this correctly to trigger when an update is necessary.

Comment: Pinning with local storage is different to caching.  With caching if there is a cache miss then the data will automatically be retrieved from the network in this case because the cache policy is `cacheElseNetwork`

Comment: Actually, Paul, you are wrong, read search through the Parse SDK now that it is open source and as I thought, these caching mechanism invoke the same pinning mechanism. Thanks for playing.

Comment: The cache and pinning use the local store, but if the local data store isn't explicitly enabled and pinning isn't explicitly performed (as is the case in this question) then you don't need to perform the operations you have suggested on the local store. You can simply specify the cache option you want and let Parse sort it out as it has always done

Comment: BUT, it's the same mechanism, they both pin

Comment: No, they don't.  If you explicitly pin an object then you will *always* get the local object (equivalent to `kPFCachePolicyCacheOnly`).

Comment: Found this answer very helpful. @Paulw11 why don't you post another answer for comparison?